# Count Values Based on Date and Reference Excel Formula or VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

By no choice of my own, I am required to create a schedule in Excel before I upload (read copy) into the scheduling app that we use. What I need to show is the number a 'p', 's', 'f', etc. days that a person is scheduled for (p1, p2). In the monthly totals at the bottom (this will go to its own sheet later), I want Excel to look at the first column in the monthly totals, see p1, then go up to the schedule and count every 'p', 's', 'f', etc. for the month.

Right now, I have COUNTIFS statements doing that calculation with the range fixed within statement itself. Right now my COUNTIFS statements are probably pretty simple. For the p1 totals I have `COUNTIFS(B2:B31,"p")`. I have a COUNTIFS for each requirement that I have to manually adjust the range for each month for each person (31 total and increasing). The example attached is the smallest of 4 sheets.

I feel like a VBA do while loop with an if in there would work but my VBA is rusty and with excel its non-existent. If there is a way to do it with formulas, I am open to that too. I have tried a couple of youtubes and looked at the Microsoft docs on VBA as well.

[image: Excel Reference]

Comment: This can certainly be handled with formulas. Why don't you show us which formulas you have tried so we can see where this data is located? You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71788415/edit) at any time.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thank you for the suggestion. I went back and added some additional info.

Comment: That's nice but what has `COUNTIFS(B2:B31,"p")` got to do with it? B2:B31 is 30 cells in a column. The dates are in a row.

Comment: I want it to read the name A7, find the matching row (A2), and then read the column and see that B, C, D columns are Apr and then look for and count all the p that are in Apr and drop that total in the appropriate spot (C7 in this case). The idea is that if there are any shifts in name order or sheet location, Excel would 'find' it on its next update.